# Cordova - Don't zoom or scale header footer in inAppBrowser while maximum-scale > 1

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova, inappbrowser

I want to zoom a webpage inside inAppBrowser. I'm using **Jquery Mobile**. So I loaded the page with `maximum-scale=5`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

So it allows me to zoom the page with touch. But I don't want to some part of the page to get bigger. Like the header footer.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"  data-theme='b' data-tap-toggle="false">

    <h1>My App</h1>

</div><!--Header-->
```

But with total page it gets bigger.I tried to set

```
height: 100px;
width: 300px;
max-height: 100px;
max-width: 300px;
```

Not working. It kepps get bigger. My main intension is to set this with fixed height width so that I can use a `button` which has to be a fixed size and always inside visible screen in mobile.

Is there any way to stop scaling the header while rest of the page gets zoomed? OR is there any way to zoom a part of the page while maximum-scale=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess no more answer is coming. Lets answer it.

So far I found that it's not possible. The browser zooming is completely controlled by the user. So any element can't be in fixed size while zooming the whole page by scaling.